# Changing Rendering Screen on separate thread after an HTTP request

Tags: java, libgdx

My goal is to change the screen of a user when the game can't reach the backend anymore. My code executes as expected except the screen never changes. Here's the initial call:

```
timer.testTimeToServer(api, game);
```

Here's the timer object's class. I put (my url) in place of the actual IP address of my backend:

```
public class CustomTimer {
private static final float timeToDrop = 2000;
private float time = 0;
private StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();

public void testTimeToServer(ApiCall api,final proofOfConcept game){
    watch.start();
    api.httpGetWithCallback("(my url)/api/v1/character", new CallBack(){
        @Override
        public void callback(String resp){
            System.out.println("Server Responded");
            time = watch.getTime();
            watch.stop();
            watch.reset();
            if(time > timeToDrop){
                game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game, false));
                System.out.println("Should have switched screen")
            }
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Here's the httpGetWithCallback method in the api object:

```
public void httpGetWithCallback (final String URL, final CallBack callback){
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {

                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {

                                             Net.HttpRequest httpRequest = new Net.HttpRequest(Net.HttpMethods.GET);
                                             httpRequest.setUrl(URL);
                                             httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                             httpRequest.setTimeOut(timeoutTimeInMilli);
                                             Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(httpRequest, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse) {
                                                     String successValue = httpResponse.getResultAsString();
                                                     if (successValue.contains("\"total_count\": 0"))//wrong credentials
                                                     {
                                                         callback.callback("EMPTY");
                                                     } else//there was a match yo! should probably have a unique conststraint on username. too hard eff it
                                                     {
                                                         callback.callback(successValue);
                                                     }
                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void failed(Throwable t) {
                                                     callback.callback("FAILED");
                                                 }

                                                 @Override
                                                 public void cancelled() {
                                                     callback.callback("CANCELLED");
                                                 }
                                             });
                                         }
                                     }
                );
            }
    });

    th.start();
    threads.add(th);
}
```

I'm stumped because the code prints out "Should have switched screens" so it's acting like expected except for the fact that the game is frozen up and the screen switch never actually happens.

Comment: OpenGL does not handle multithreading well.

Comment: did you try to create a validation inside the render method that changes the screen? 
In java when you pass variables to methods they are copies of the instance, so calling game.setScreen 
inside this method will do nothing to the original instance, this is not a pointer like C,C++. You need to acess the game object in a static way or validate it inside the render method and change the screen. Oh, and you need to call dispose(); after changing screen too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Lazy Way:**

on your main game class:

```
public static ProofOfConcept game;
```

and your method

```
public void testTimeToServer(ApiCall api){
    watch.start();
    api.httpGetWithCallback("(my url)/api/v1/character", new CallBack(){
        @Override
        public void callback(String resp){
            System.out.println("Server Responded");
            time = watch.getTime();
            watch.stop();
            watch.reset();
            if(time > timeToDrop){
                Main.game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(false));
                System.out.println("Should have switched screen")
            }
        }
    });
   }
}
```

**The Right Way**

You can create a callback inside your ProofOfConcept class that every frame on the render method checks the result and change the screen.

Comment: Nice, that was it! Thanks a bunch!